# Counting the number of elements of blocks with same consecutive elements

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having the following problem:

A park that have the form of a m x n board. There are k kinds of trees (1 <= k <= 100). The park is divided into m x n cells and each cell, they'll plant a tree. Now, on the map, each cell of the park have an integer i inside if the i-th kind of tree is planted in it, or a 0 if no tree is planted in it. A line of cells is considered "good" if it has at least t trees of same types, (and they must be on the same either line or column). Count the number of trees that is not in a "good" line.

Input: Integers m, n, t and an m x n array of integers represent the map.

Output: Number of trees that is not in a "good" line.

Example:

**Input:**
5 6 3

1 3 3 3 3 4

1 2 3 2 0 4

3 2 2 2 4 4

1 0 0 2 4 0

1 2 3 0 4 4

**Output:** 10

**Explanation:** The bold numbers are the trees that is not in a good line.

**1** 3 3 3 3 4

**1 2 3** 2 0 4

**3** 2 2 2 4 4

**1** 0 0 2 4 0

**1 2 3** 0 4 **4**

My idea is to check for each element in the array. If it is satisfied then I'll move to the nearest element outside the "good" line. Else, it will just move to the next element on the same line, or if the line is ended then the next element on the column.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define maxn 120

int a[maxn][maxn], m, n, t;

int check(int *i, int *j){
    int k, cnt_r, cnt_c;
    cnt_r = 0;
    //jump to the nearest cell that is not in good line
    for(k = *i + 1; k < m; k++){
        if(a[*i][*j] == a[k][*j]) cnt_r++;
        if(cnt_r >= t){
            *i = k;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    cnt_c = 0;
    for(k = *j + 1; k < n; k++){
        if(a[*i][*j] == a[*i][k]) cnt_c++;
        if(cnt_c >= t){
            *j = k;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
//check if this is the last square or not
int lastSq(int r, int c){
    return (r == n - 1 && c == n);
}

int main(){
    int res = 0, i, j, pos_r = 0, pos_c = 0;
    scanf("%d%d%d", &m, &n, &t);
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);

    while(!lastSq(pos_r, pos_c)){
        if(a[pos_r][pos_c] == 0){
            if(pos_c < n - 1) pos_c++;
            else if(pos_r < n - 1){
                pos_c = 0;
                pos_r++;
            }
        }
        if(!check(&pos_r, &pos_c)){
            res++;
            if(pos_c < n - 1) pos_c++;
            else{
                pos_c = 0;
                pos_r++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d", res);
}
```

But it doesn't print any output. The only thing I have is 0xC0000005. Can someone please check where did I make a mistake and provide me a direction? Thanks.

Comment: Too many stars! You don't need to update the pointed to ints all the time

Comment: What's the value of `t`?

Comment: "A line of cells is considered "good" if it has at least t trees of same types, (and they must be on the same either line or column)" The value t is to determine if a line is good or not. In our example, t = 3.

Comment: How do you know if `scanf("%d%d%d", &m, &n, &t);` succeeds? (and `scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);`?)

Comment: code like `(a[*i][*j] == a[k][*j]` is a big red flag to me.  I'd be adding NULL checks and range checks to this as more than likely, this is where your bad memory access is occurring.  In truth, your debugger will tell you exactly which line your bad read/write happens and should let your read your variables as well on where the crash occurred.  Seeing an i/j/k with a bad value in it would be a big clue to you.  Adding debug printf() can also work in cases where you don't have a debugger, but is far inferior.

Comment: What's a "line"? Is it the same thing as "row or column"? What lines in your input do you consider good?

Comment: As I said, a line is formed by same consecutive elements on a same row or column. A line is consider good if its length is not less than the number t specified in the input. For example, we have row 1 2 2 2 2 3 and t = 3 then the line 2 2 2 2 is good while 1 and 3 are not.

Comment: The word "consecutive" doesn't appear in the assignment but does appear in your title, this could mean you are misrepresenting or misunderstanding the problem. Please post your assignment verbatim.

Comment: OT:  when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this reads like one of the online programming challenges.  Please include a link to the actual challenge.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage`  (or better, both)  all those single character names are meaningless, even in the current context.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.  3) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line  4) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)  (cont)

Comment: OT: (cont) 5) always include the optional braces '{' and '}' around `for()`, `if` `else` `while` etc code blocks

Comment: the posted code 'hard codes' the size of the 'board'.  Isn't that something being read in?  If so, then use the VLA (variable length array) feature of C

Comment: please post some representative data input, so we have some idea as to what the code should expect